# Many-one reductions between the set of true sentences and a particular arithmetical set

Tags: undecidability, arithmetic, incompleteness

Never used this site before so not sure the best way to get help. However, I've been looking at many-one reductions in relations to sentences in logic.

Let TH(N) = {ϕ : ϕ is a first order sentence in the language of arithmetic and N |= ϕ} (Where N is the standard model of arithmetic - , x, <, +, 0, and the successor; S)

Let γ(x) be some formula with exactly one free variable, namely x. Then assume X = {n : γ(n)} to be the arithmetical subset of the natural numbers defined by γ(x).

My question is: Is there a way to show either of X or TH(N) many one-reduce to each other?

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER**SCIENCE** @SE. `[Newbie not sure about] the best way to get help` There is a [help centre](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help) including [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) My favourite advice is *Picture yourself addressing a peer busy with something else*.

Answer (score 1):

For any such $X$ we have $X\le_mTh(\mathbb{N})$ but not conversely (and in fact $Th(\mathbb{N})$ is **vastly** more complicated than $X$).

To see that $X\le_mTh(\mathbb{N})$, we want to translate a question of the form "Is $n\in X$?" into one of the form "Is $\psi_n$ a true sentence?" for some appropriate sentence $\psi_n$. Now "$n\in X$" is equivalent to "$\gamma(n)$," and that's **almost** a sentence in the language of arithmetic - the only issue is that "$n$" isn't a symbol in the language of arithmetic (which consists only of $0,1,+,\times,<$). Do you see a quick way around this?

> Each natural number $n$ has a corresponding **numeral**, usually denoted "$\underline{n}$," which is just an appropriate string of the symbols $0$," "$1$," "$($," and "$)$" (or is the symbol "$0$" if $n$ is $0$): e.g. $\underline{4}$ is the string $((1+1)+1)+1$. Then if we let $\psi_n=\gamma(\underline{n})$, we have that $\psi_n\in Th(\mathbb{N})$ iff $n\in X$.

Note that here I'm conflating e.g. the *number* $0$ and the *constant symbol* $0$; this is annoying, but standard.

---

The other direction is a consequence of [Tarski's undefinability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem): just show that anything many-one reducible (or even Turing-reducible) to an arithmetically definable set is itself arithmetically definable. This will show that we never have $Th(\mathbb{N})\le_mX$ (or even $\le_TX$) for such an $X$. The key here is to show that the basic notions of computability theory are arithmetically definable:

> Use [Kleene's $T$-predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_T_predicate) to talk about computable reductions.